# MySQL nested sums with multiple joins and group by

Tags: mysql

I have following tables my result is always incorrect

Table 1 : **product_category**

```
  |  id |   title       |
  |  1  |   Electronics |
  |  2  |   Kitchen     |
```

Table 2 : **sold_items**

```
| id | product_id | invoiceid | product_category_id | qty |
| 1  | 91         | 1001      | 1                   |  2  |
| 2  | 92         | 1001      | 1                   |  3  |
| 3  | 93         | 1002      | 2                   |  7  |
| 4  | 94         | 1002      | 2                   |  3  |
| 5  | 93         | 1003      | 2                   |  15  |
```

Table 3 : **profit_table**

```
| invoiceid | profit | cost   |
| 1001      | 200.00 | 980.00 |
| 1002      | 100.00 | 700.00 |
| 1003      | 350.00 | 900.00 |
```

Table 4 : **product_log**

```
| id | product_id | qty | tdate       | invoiceid |
| 1  | 91         |  2  | 2017-01-10  | 1001      |
| 2  | 92         |  3  | 2017-01-10  | 1001      |
| 3  | 93         |  7  | 2017-02-10  | 1002      |
| 4  | 94         |  3  | 2017-02-10  | 1002      |
| 5  | 93         |  15 | 2017-03-10  | 1003      |
```

I want to sum(profit_table.profit), MONTH(product_log.tdate),SUM(sold_items.qty)
Where result should be product_category wise and month wise and where condition should be like YEAR(product_log.tdate)=2017

Example **result_view**

```
| title      | MONTH(product_log.tdate) | sum(profit) |SUM(sold_items.qty) |
| Electronics| 1                        | 200         | 5                  |
| Kitchen    | 2                        | 100         | 10                 |
| Kitchen    | 3                        | 350         | 15                 |
```

Please suggest me a correct query

As per my research result will like

```
SELECT r.totalqty,
       f.profit,
       p.mymonth,
       c.title
FROM (SELECT invoiceid,Sum(qty) totalqty,product_category_id 
        FROM   sold_items 
        GROUP  BY sold_items.product_category_id) AS r 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceid,Sum(profit) profit FROM profit_table GROUP BY profit_table.invoiceid) AS f ON r.tid = f.tid
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT tid,DATE(tdate) mymonth FROM pstatements) AS p 
        ON r.invoiceid = p.invoiceid
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,title FROM product_category) AS c 
        ON r.product_category_id = c.id
 WHERE YEAR(p.mymonth)='2017' GROUP BY DATE(p.tdate)
```

**This is not a correct result still a clue if you want answer**

Comment: What did you try so far ? Which incorrect result did you get ?

Comment: I have tried many combinations sometime I get get double sum and not getting correct group by also. If  you can write than please write a query to achieve example result_view

Comment: @SatishGarg sir calculations are not correct because you are doing a simple left_join  additionally you can give me table structure suggestion.

Comment: @Piyush There is no `left join` in the answer i posted.

Comment: @SatishGarg Sorry sir! inner join but I want tell you that product id is primary/unique with category id. Each pid 91 catid 1 for 93 catid 2.. I have edited question data ..Hope it will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The below written query should work.

You can access the [sqlfiddle for this schema here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c009a/9).

```
select pc.title, month(pl.tdate), pt.profit, sum(si.qty) 
from product_category pc
inner join sold_items si on si.product_category_id = pc.id
inner join profit_table pt on pt.invoiceid = si.invoiceid
inner join product_log pl on pl.invoiceid = pt.invoiceid
where si.product_id = pl.product_id  
group by pc.title,pl.tdate
order by month(pl.tdate) asc ;
```

Comment: Nice work: you actually created an SQLfiddle and checked that your query works ;)

Comment: Hehe. Thanks. Had to check. No one likes a buggy piece of code :-)

Comment: Oh ok, let me check.

Comment: Updated the answer. Note the `where` clause for deduping. Also replace `pt.profit` by `sum(pt.profit)` to get the correct answer.

Comment: Your expected result seems to be incorrect as for `month=1` and `month=2`, the `profit` should be `200+200` (one for each `product_id`).
In that case, replace `pt.profit` by `sum(pt.profit)`.

Answer (score 0):

YOU should use SOME JOIN AND  group by

```
select  
    product_category.title
  , MONTH(product_log.tdate)
  , sum(profit)
  , SUM(sold_items.qty) 
from product_category 
left join  sold_items on  sold_items.product_category_id =  product_category.id
left join product_log  on product_log.product_id = sold_items.product_id
left join profit_table on profit_table.invoiceid = product_log.invoiceid
group by  product_category.title, MONTH(product_log.tdate)
```

Comment: Sir,there is no product_id in profit table (I corrected it by replacing with invoice_id )and getting double sum

Answer (score 0):

You would need to join the tables on their keys and group by the product and transaction month.  Something like the below:

```
select pc.title, month(pl.tdate) as tmonth, sum(pt.profit) as month_profit, sum(si.qty) as month_qty
  from product_category pc
  left join sold_items si
    on si.product_category_id = pc.id
  left join profit_table pt
    on pt.invoice_id = si.invoice_id
  left join product_log pl
    on pl.product_id = si.product_id
   and pl.invoice_id = si.invoice_id
 group by pc.id, month(pl.tdate)
 where year(pl.tdate) = '2017';
```

Comment: Getting NULL month in some records

Comment: @Piyush - I used si.product_id where I should have used si.product_category_id.